# Concatenate array to form a string

Tags: arrays, excel, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a value of angles in two cells:

```
theta1    theta 2
1          10
2           9
3           8
4           7
```

I need to concatenate them to perform either sine or cosine function of theta(1,2) in order to graph them. This is for an airfoil project in which I have two values for theta which I need to make into one (string or array) and perform one more calculation with this one string or array and plot the results.

I do not want to add the values like turn `1` and `5` into `fifteen`, NO! rather turn `1` and `5` into theta = [1, 5], where I can then perform sine or cosine on theta and get value for sin(theta) = { x, y } or cos(theta) = {x,y}. I would then need to plot sine versus cosine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Those theta values are all messed up. ....

Comment: Theta1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Theta2= (10, 9, 8, 7)

Comment: I then need to concatenate (theta1, theta2) to form theta(final)

Comment: This final "theta" function will be used to perform one more calculation and then be graphed.

Comment: Therefore thera(final) = [theta1, theta2].

Comment: But I need to be able to use this theta(final) in another equation. This result should also be in the form [result1, result2] and I should be able to plot it. It is a thickness distribution equation on an airfoil.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are in A1:B4:

```
(Theta(A1,A2,A3,A4),Theta(B1,B2,B3,B4))
```

Or am I missing something?